# Count if or Count where in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a data set of contracts and the nationalities of people working on them.  A sample is as follows.

```
Contract  Country
GTT001    DE
GTT001    DE
GTT001    US
BFF333    US
BFF333    US
BFF333    DE
HHH222    GB
HHH222    GB
HHH222    GB
```

I need a query that will count the number of people working on each contract from each country.  So one that will produce a table like below:

```
         DE   US    GB
GTT001   2    1     0
BFF333   1    2     0
HHH222   0    0     3
```

I am working in Access 2010.  Is there a countif or some equivalent that will allow me to count values based on conditions?

Comment: It's called *Pivot*. It should be easier to find an answer when you know how the thing you're looking for is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   DECLARE @Pivotcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
      select @Pivotcols = STUFF((SELECT distinct N',' + QUOTENAME([Country]) 
                from [Contract]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

    select @Pivotcols

    set @query = N'SELECT [Contract], ' + @Pivotcols + N' 
        from 
        (
           SELECT   [Contract]
  ,[Country]
   FROM [TEST_DB].[dbo].[Contract]

        ) sourceTable
        pivot 
        (
            Count([Country])
            for [Country] in (' + @Pivotcols + N')
        ) p '

  execute sp_executesql @query;
```

The core query

```
  SELECT * from
  (SELECT   [Contract]
     ,[Country]
   FROM [TEST_DB].[dbo].[Contract]
  ) sT
    pivot 
        (
            Count([Country])
            for [Country] in ([DE],[US],[GB])
        ) p
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use GROUP BY using both contract and then country.  This will give you a list like this:

```
Contract  Country   Count
GTT001    DE        2
GTT001    US        1
BFF333    US        2
BFF333    DE        1
HHH222    GB        3
```

Then you want to pivot those values to get it into the format you want. The 0s will still be missing...

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT will work, it's a bit more complicated but so raw sql you could GROUP BY, for example:

SELECT Contract, Country, COUNT(*)
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY Contract, Country
ORDER BY Country